# Issue routing default route in MVC with Attribute Routes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, url-routing

I am trying to find out why the routing of these two sittuations are not functioing. I want to conver this rout in the Routes.config file to a route attribute. It needs to be a default, because when you just load the site, without any url entered, it needs to hit /Home/Index action.

```
             routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

I added this to the Home controller for the actionResult Index(), but it didn't work. Said no document loaded.

```
[Route]
[Route("~/", Name = "default")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var environmentsSharedAccounts = new List<EnvironmentSharedAccountVM>();


    return View(environmentsSharedAccounts);
}
```

Why does this now not resolve. Thanks in advance.  BTW. I am finding, that the books I have read, and the examples I have seen are seeming to be more compleicated to me then I thought I guess, because this routing has been giving me issues. I think I understand it, but it doesn't work how expected. Anyways....

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
[Route("")]
public ActionResult Index() 
....
```

Do you have this line on WebApiConfig.cs :

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

?